# PHP - Check <option> value is equal to <input> value

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm writing a website that allows for people to add movies into a database.

At the moment the user can either select from a director that is already within the database or create a new one.

```
            <div class='dropdownrow' id='director_namerow'>
            <div>
                <label for='director_name'>Director:</label>
                <select name='director_name'>
                    <option value='blank' selected>Select...</option>
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * 
                                FROM director
                                ORDER BY director_name ASC";
                        $director = mysql_query($sql);
                                    while ($directors=mysql_fetch_array($director)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $directors['director_id']; ?>"><?php echo $directors['director_name']; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                </select>
                <span style = 'color:red;'> *</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for='director_namenew'>Or new director:</label>
                <input type='text' name='director_namenew' size='25' maxlength='128' />
            </div>
        </div>
```

So the problem is, how do I check that "director_namenew" isn't equal to "director_name" AND that director_namenew isn't already within the database.

Furthermore, is the "director_namenew" isn't within the database, I need to add them into the database too.

Controller Script

```
  function validateDirector ($formdata) {
   if(($formdata['director_name'] == "blank") && ($formdata['director_namenew'] == "")){
    return false;   
   }
    else if($formdata['hidden_director_name'] == $formdata['director_namenew']){
        echo 'cannot have directors match';
        return false;
    }
    else {
     return true;   
    }
} // TO COMPLETE
```

Thanks guys, 
pb.

Comment: Cool dropdown, but where's your controller code?

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by controller code? #newToPHP

Comment: If you're learning, you may as well learn a proper paradigm. Google "MVC Development" -- I'd recommend finding yourself a good PHP Framework as well (I personally enjoy Laravel). It will make life a lot easier, I promise.

Comment: ohhhh, I know what you mean, I can't. I've been told we have to use pure OOP PHP...

Comment: Controller is the script that runs when you submit the form. You just showed the script that creates the form.

Comment: You can run a query like `SELECT director_id FROM director WHERE director_name = '$director_namenew'`. This should return 0 rows to indicate that the director is not in the database.

Comment: I have updated with the controller script within the question.

Comment: What is "pure OOP PHP?" Because, frameworks leverage "pure PHP." Is this for some assignment?

Comment: @Blake Correct - assignment for uni, all completed just can't figure this out....

Comment: U can loop through your directors table with foreach and put results in an array then later u can check with if(in_array($_POST["director_namenew"],$loopedarray)){}

Comment: There are plenty of ways to achieve that but if you really want to keep it simple, change the query. BTW, if this code is going to be used in live website, you should seriously use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to transfer the front-end requirement to back-end so that seperate the view and controller.

*view.html* (Some modification base on your original code):

```
<script src="checkRepeatName.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for='director_namenew'>Or new director:</label>
  <input type='text' name='director_namenew' size='25' maxlength='128' />
  <span id="notation"></span>
</div>
```

*checkRepeatName.js* (Written with jQuery):

```
$("input[name='director_namenew']").change(function(){
 $.get("backend.php?dnamenew=" + this.value,function(data,status){
  $(".notation").text(data);
 });
});
```

*backend.php* (I use Object Oriented Style of PHP code,and refer the recommendation of @Barmar):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['dnamenew'])) {
  $director_namenew = $_GET['dnamenew'];
};

$dbconn = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME, PORT);
$sqlStat =  sprintf('SELECT director_id FROM director WHERE director_name = "%s";', $director_namenew);
if ($sqlQuery = $dbconn->query($sqlStat)){
  if ($sqlQuery->num_rows == 0){
    echo 'This is validated database name';
  } else {
    echo 'Invalidated database name!';
  }
}
$dbconn->close;
?>
```

-------- supplement something --------
It maybe something help in design dynamic dropdown menu with MVC design pattern

*view.html*:

```
<div class='dropdownrow' id='director_namerow'>
  <div>
    <label for='director_name'>Director:</label>
    <select name='director_name'>
      <option value='blank' selected>Select...</option>                                 
    </select>
    <span style = 'color:red;'> *</span>
  </div>
<div>
```

*controllor.js*:

```
 $("select[name='director_name']").change(function(){
   $.get("optionOutput.php", function(data,status){
     $("select[name='director_name']").append(data); // append the call-back message from back-end file
 });
});
```

*optionOutput.php*:

```
<?php
include 'dbmng/dbconfig.php';
$dbconn = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME, PORT);
$sqlStat = 'SELECT * FROM director ORDER BY director_name ASC;';
if ($sqlQue = $dbconn->query($sqlStat)){
  while($sqlRes = $sqlQue->fetch_assoc()){
    $output = sprintf('<option value = "%d">%s</option>', $sqlResult['director_id'], $sqlRes['director_name']);
    echo $output;
  }
}
$dbconn->close;
?>
```

Comment: I have posted an answer to my own question, what do you think?

Comment: Using `foreach` statement maybe redundant,I strongly recommend the method that retrieving the return result rows number to check whether republicate record exist or not.In addtion,you can use `REGEXP` statment in SQL query to extend more function of text match.

Comment: To check if both the drop down and input field have been filled,maybe better to check within the front-end with JavaScript rather than within back-end.I think it is better to use back-end script to  exisistence of database query

Comment: I have to make sure this form only validates by using PHP and no other language.

Comment: I know its pretty bad, but this is what i've come up with

Comment: else if(($formdata['director_name'] != "blank") && ($formdata['director_namenew'] != "")){
        print "<p>Either use the dropdown for Director or enter a new director in the textbox. - Use the back button on your browser to rectify this problem.</p>";
        return false;
    }

Comment: eh...that is okay,I recommend the PHP builtin function `isset()` or  `is_null()` to check the value from front-end transfered in GET or POST method rather than the simple expssion in condition statment as `if ($var){ //do sth... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question

```
if(($formdata['director_name'] == "blank") && ($formdata['director_namenew'] == "")){
            print "<p>Please enter in director information - Use the back button on your browser to rectify this problem.</p>";
            return false;   
           }
            else if($formdata['director_namenew']) {
                $doesntExist = true;
                $db = getDBConnection();
                $directors = $db->query("SELECT director_name FROM director");
                //Check each one
                foreach ($directors as $director){
                    //If the username is already in the DB stop looking
                    if($formdata['director_namenew'] == $director['director_name']){
                        $doesntExist = false;
                        print "<p>Director entered in new director already exists, please enter in new director or select from drop down menu - Use the back button on your browser to rectify this problem.</p>";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //DB connection closed when PDO object isn't referenced
                //ie setting $db to null closes the connection
                $db = null;
                return $doesntExist;
            }
```

-- However, how would I check to see if both the drop down and input field have been filled?

I was thinking something like:

```
else if(($formdata['director_name']) && ($formdata['director_namenew'])) {
    print "Please select either new director or director from drop down menu";
}
```

And checking on the submit to see if both $_POST variables have been submitted.

What do you think?